# What will happen to this fan in this situation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, energy, fan

Lets say I have a pipe with a fan at the end of it and it is drawing ambient air from the other end of the pipe. Once I account for some blockages and looking at the fan curve, it was found the operating point is 200 CFM. This means 200 CFM will enter from the outside environment from the other end of the pipe.

Now lets say I introduce a hole in the pipe and manually force in 100 CFM from some other system. Since the fan is designed for 200 CFM, will it only draw 100 CFM from the ambient environment to make 200 CFM total? Or will it still draw the 200 CFM from the ambient environment and add this 100 CFM to make 300 CFM total. If that is the case, we are forcing more air through the fan than it was designed for. Will this be potentially damaging to the fan?

Comment: If a plane is flying in a tailwind, does it go faster?

Comment: answering your one yes/no question does not provide one answer for my multiple questions. the answer to your question is Yes, but which question of mine does that answer?

Comment: It might depend on the fan, but in general, a fan capable of 200 CFM can draw more if the air is already moving toward it.

Comment: I'd try a delta mass approach.  If a 200 CFM fan can move 200 CF of stationary air mass per minute,  then it should have the same delta mass even if some of the air is already moving.